# Regex PHP , conditions

Tags: php, regex

I work on a project which consist to sort address .

I got a typical address for example : `25 Down Street 15000 London` .

On another side i got a more specific address with for example `25 **B** Down Street 15000 London`.

I found a way to only select number of streets with this regex : `\b([1-9][0-9]{0,2})` .

But as you can see some address contains another letter which is part of the number (like 25 A , 25 B ..)

So now i search regex able to find numbers of street even if it contains more than just the number .

Example : If the address is `25 Down Street` (I want to find 25) and if the address is `25 B Down Street` (I want to find `25 B`)

Keep searching, but maybe you got an idea to help me .

Thank you

Comment: How can you be sure that you will match a letter belonging to the number, but not to the street name? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ0aM4/2). Are there any assumptions?

Comment: If only one letter follow the number it means that this is an information related to the number my datas are build on this principle . I have tested your regexp and works perfectly . (You can ad the answer for other people) and thank you .

Comment: Edit : what if i don't search only one letter but a specific word ? 
The example should be : 25 BIS Down Street ? the specific word here is BIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one Latin letter after the first 1-3-digit number in string, you can use the following regex:

```
'/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\s*[A-Z])?\b/'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZ0aM4/3)

The word boundary `\b` will make sure there is no word character after the Latin letter after the first number followed with optional whitespace. If the letter is missing, the `\b` will still make sure the number is followed by a non-word character, which seems to fit your requirements.

If you want to just assume the *next ALLCAPS word after the first number* belongs to the number, use:

```
'/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\s*[A-Z]+)?\b/' 
                             ^
```